# Restarting apache during nominatim import

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm updating Europe Database via nominatim from this post on my server.
https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/15505/import-more-osm-files-in-to-nominatim
Today is 12/20GB and It's 6th day of import so it's going very slow. In my apache & php I have to enable CURL extension so i need to restart apache. Is Nominatim using apache to update and index database ? When I will restart apache process that will cause nominatim update stop  ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this myself but the import should not require a running Apache instance as that would be a rather unfortunate approach. According to [utils/update.php](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/blob/master/utils/update.php) it calls `Nominatim` and `osm2pgsql` directly. Thus, restarting Apache should be fine.